# Do I need to explicitly close connections when using GridView control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database-connection

When working with databound controls in asp.net, is there a good pattern for making sure everything is disposed properly?

Here's what I have so far:

```
        using (var conn = New SqlConnection("connectionString"))
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "myProc";

            conn.Open();
            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                gridview1.DataSource = rdr;
                gridview1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Do I need to close the datareader / command / connection? Or does the using statement take care of this automatically? Or maybe there is a better pattern when using databound controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems right. The only possible changes are:

1. No need to associate the connection to the command when you use the CreateCommand
2. Add a `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` to the ExecuteReader (no really necessary with the flow of `using` statements)

But they are really little things.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sounds like I was on the right track, but the improvements are good to hear as well.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to take care about the disposing the object when using `using` statement.`using` statement calls `dispose()` method in finally block which causes the object itself to go out of scope as soon as Dispose is called

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So is my code sample "perfect" as it is? Well, as far as my code is ever perfect ;) Or would you recommend any changes?

Answer (score 1):

Using `'using'` statement calls dispose method itself so you don't need to take care of it. However you can use one of the following:

1. If you  want to paging and sorting enabled then you need to Load
       data to DataTable first and then close the your connections and
       readers like following :

   ```
    var rdr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       dt.Load(rdr);
       rdr.Close();
       gridview1.DataSource = dt;
       gridview1.DataBind();
   ```
2. If you don't want paging and sorting enabled then you can bind data
       to gridview and then close the reader after loading it to gridview like:

   ```
        gridview1.DataSource = rdr;
        gridview1.DataBind();
        rdr.Close();
   ```

Comment: PLease review your answer, in particular that first line to avoid downvote.

Comment: First of all thanks for update. Secondly, 'Is it apt now...?' If not then please give me suggestion for improving it. All suggestions are welcome.